# Proving number of matches played in a knock-out tournament with $n$ players is $n-1$ using induction

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, induction

I am supposed to prove that if $n$ players play in $n-1$ ways. Clearly the base case is trivially true, whence only $1$ match will be played. Also the case when the number of players is of the form $2^k$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, can be easily formulated as follows. $$2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+2^{k-3}+\ldots+2+1=2^{k}-1$$

I am not sure how to use induction on it in the general case, including the case when $n$ is odd. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Starting with $n$ players, you want to finish with $1$ winner. At each game, you eliminate exactly $1$ player. You want to eliminate $n-1$ players, so you need $n-1$ games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly true, because everyone but the winner loses one game, and each game has one loser.

For an inductive proof, say there are $n>1$ players and the theorem is true for a knockout tournament with $n-1$ players.  Consider the very first game played.  The winner is then is a knockout tournament with the remaining $n-2$ players.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that my proof is by induction, but I'll give it anyway.

The tournament starts with $n$ players.

Each match eliminates exactly one player from the tournament.

There is exactly $1$ winner.

Therefore, there must be $n-1$ matches.

$[n - 1 - 1 - 1 ... - 1 = 1.$ There must be $(n-1)\ $ "$-1$'s", and each $-1$ represents a match (someone losing a match, in fact).]